# Как прочитать XML?

Tags: c#, xml

Всем привет.

Я записал файл user.xml таким образом

```
<Пользователь>Афанасий</Пользователь>
<Пол>Мужчина</Пол>
<Дата>
    <Год>1988</Год>
    <Месяц>5</Месяц>
    <День>5</День>
    <Род деятельности>Путешествия</Род деятельности>
</Дата>

<Пользователь>Марина</Пользователь>
<Пол>Женский</Пол>
<Дата>
    <Год>1968</Год>
    <Месяц>2</Месяц>
    <День>12</День>
    <Род деятельности>Путешествия</Род деятельности>
</Дата>

<Пользователь>Димон</Пользователь>
<Пол>Мужчина</Пол>
<Дата>
    <Год>1588</Год>
    <Месяц>5</Месяц>
    <День>31</День>
    <Род деятельности>Путешествия</Род деятельности>
</Дата>
```

Я хочу, чтобы программа прочитала файл, и выбрала данные, и поместила их в переменную. Пример: сегодня 28.03.12, и если программа видит, что есть дата 3.04.12 и меньше, то перенести их в переменные

```
int day = 0;
int month = 0;
int year = 0;
```

Ну, и дальше работать с ними, просто XML для меня что-то новое, искал на ютубе, не нашёл, на MSDN слишком много всем, и не понятно, где есть что и в итоге запутываешься.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Xml документы хорошо парсятся LINQ'ом.

```
XElement source = XElement.Load(@"source.xml");

var parsed = (from date in source.Descendants("Дата")
let d = new
{
    Day = date.Element("День").Value,
    Month = date.Element("Месяц").Value,
    Year = date.Element("Год").Value
}
select d)
.ToArray();
```

Сейчас проверить негде, но должно работать.

Comment: Ошибка:

    There are multiple root elements. Line 2, position 2.

Comment: оберните все в <xml></xml>

Comment: Как это сделать?

Comment: В начале документа (первая строка), введите `<xml>`, в конце документа, на последнем символе, вставьте `</xml>`.

Answer (score 2):

Есть несколько способов записи данных в Xml файл:

1. Сериализация. Использовав пространство имён `System.Runtime.Serialization.Xml` можно с лёгкостью записывать данные в файлы формата Xml. Для этого, используется класс `XmlFormatter`.
2. Linq to XML. Запись, чтение и редактирование данных осуществляется при пространства имён `System.Xml.Linq`.
3. Так же можно читать и записывать данные использовав пространство имён `System.Xml`.

Для подробного изучения информации, рекомендую прочитать руководство на русском языке:

1. http://metanit.com/sharp/tutorial/6.4.php
2. http://metanit.com/sharp/tutorial/16.5.php
3. http://metanit.com/sharp/tutorial/16.1.php

Ссылка на руководство, для каждого пункта, соответственно.

P.S. XML тэги не рекомендуется писать кириллицей, используйте латинские символы.